# maas not starting up anymore

Tags: maas

The mass region is no longer coming up.

The version that I am using is:
1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2~vivid1

This seemed to happen after the update to 1.8

```
root@maas:/var/log/maas# export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=maas.settings
root@maas:/var/log/maas# export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/maas
root@maas:/var/log/maas# export LOGFILE=/var/log/maas/regiond.log
root@maas:/var/log/maas# /usr/bin/twistd --nodaemon --pidfile= maas-regiond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/twistd", line 14, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 27, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 642, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 376, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 436, in createOrGetApplication
    ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/plugin.py", line 92, in makeService
    self._configureDjango()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/plugin.py", line 71, in _configureDjango
    django_setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/share/maas/maas/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    object.__setattr__(django.conf.settings, "__class__", LazySettings)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this also, with MAAS 1.9 (following OpenStack setup instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot). Was able to workaround by commenting out this line right on my machine's filesystem (although in my setup it's line 115, I think it's 1.8/1.9 diff):

File "/usr/share/maas/maas/**init**.py", line 128, in 
    object.**setattr**(django.conf.settings, "**class**", LazySettings)

After so doing the regiond has started emitting normal logs and the MAAS web page shows up correctly.

The line above seems to help disable some undesirable logs - unfortunately it also kills MAAS, so I figure commenting out is not so bad.